# Trouble Aggregating Rows with SQL Statement

Tags: sql, pivot, case, sql-server-2012

I am attempting to pivot some data out of the `Vendor` column in this table, creating new columns for each of my vendors.  Ideally, I would have 1 row for each `ContractDate`, and then 2 values.  However, I'm ending up with 2 rows of a distinct `ContractDate`.

I believe i may need some sort of temp table query to do this...i'm not sure though.

```
SELECT [ContractDate], 
       CASE WHEN Vendor = 'AirDat' 
            THEN (sum(wf.Temppop) / sum(wf.Population)) END as 'AirDat',
       CASE WHEN Vendor = 'CWG' 
            THEN (sum(wf.Temppop) / sum(wf.Population)) END as 'CWG'
FROM [ECPDB].[dbo].[weather.forecast] as wf 
INNER JOIN ecpdb.[lookup].[newWeatherStation] as ws
ON wf.[Station_ID] = ws.[Station ID]
INNER JOIN ecpdb.[lookup].[CountyNew] as c
ON ws.[County FIPS] = c.[County FIPS]
WHERE tradedate = '7/2/2012'
AND [BENTEK Cell] = 'Northeast'
GROUP BY [ContractDate], vendor
```

Comment: What database platform and version are you using?

Comment: What is your table structure...

Comment: Is `tradeDate` really stored as a string (and formatted that way), or is that just the result of how you wrote the query?  It's probably better to wrap string input values (if they aren't really dates) in a date-conversion function, so that the actual data column won't be converted to string (potentially for every row).

Comment: @Kevin - sql server 2012

Comment: @X-Zero it is stored as datetime

Comment: @DavidManheim this is going through a fair number of tables, are you asking me to list all of the columns?

Comment: Well, at minimum we need to know where `vendor` is coming from.  You only have 3 tables, which isn't that many - also, we only need you to list the columns that are relevant to the query, so we don't even need all the columns.

Comment: got it - 
weather.forecast [TradeDate,ContractDate,Population,Temppop,Station_ID,Vendor]


newWeatherStation = [Station_ID, County_FIPS]


CountyNew = [County_FIPS, BENTEK_Cell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a subquery;

```
Select ContractDate, 
     max(case when Vendor = 'AirDat' THEN Vendor_Average End) as AirDAT,  
     max(case when Vendor = 'CWG' THEN Vendor_Average End) as CWG
  from (
  SELECT [ContractDate] , Vendor, (sum(wf.Temppop) / sum(wf.Population)) as Vendor_Average
  FROM [ECPDB].[dbo].[weather.forecast] as wf 
  inner join ecpdb.[lookup].[newWeatherStation] as ws
     on wf.[Station_ID] = ws.[Station ID]
  inner join ecpdb.[lookup].[CountyNew] as c
     on ws.[County FIPS] = c.[County FIPS]
  where tradedate = '7/2/2012' and [BENTEK Cell] = 'Northeast' 
group by ContractDate, Vendor
) as Subquery
     group by Contractdate
```

This way, the query runs and finds the values you need, and then you pick the rows you want without needing to group.

Comment: dropping vendor results in. Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Column 'weather.forecast.Vendor' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Sorry about that - without seeing the table structure, and understanding what is being fetched, it's harder to see what will occur. The new solution should work - but since I don't have the table structure, you may need to edit it to make sure it is correct.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error (this time in the sub-select) to add in the group by.  when i add them (Group by ContractDtae,Vendor), it does the same thing.

Comment: Besides the `GROUP BY` problem (sub-queries must still be valid SQL queries!), this won't solve the OP's problem, as it's still going to generate **2** rows, not 1 row of 2 columns.

Comment: OK, it's fixed, I think. Without the data, or a simpler similar problem, it is difficult to test the code.

Comment: The Problem could have been put simply; I have something like `select a, case when c = 'Value_1' THEN max(x) End as val1_c_max, case when c = 'Value_2' THEN max(x) End as val2_c_max`. It is returning 2 rows instead of 1. How can I fix it? This would require writing a simpler version of the query, but would allow easier answers that would be useful for others - this isn't about simply answering a question, it's building a resource. This type of question actually is not ideal, because it's completely un-re-usable, and will help no-one with the same question next time.

Comment: Makes sense - i'll keep that in mind going forward.  thank you